# How to create dropdown menu with php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This title may confuse someone, but the my goal is to make a dropdown menu with echoing it within the PHP function. To understand my problem a little bit...

My mainpages, the names are displayed at the top menu:

**TABLE INDEX_PAGES**

```
id,    name,        href
----------------------------
1     login     ?page=login    
2     admin     ?page=admin  
3     projects  ?page=projects   
4     home      ?page=home
```

The table to know what mainpages can be displayed in the top menu

**TABLE TOP_MENU**

```
id,    index_page
------------------
1     1        
2     2       
3     3  
4     4
```

***Im using function to echo them into my topmenu.***

Structure:

```
<header>
<h1 class="header">Godhaze</h1>
<nav id="nav-vasak">
<ul>
<?php echo get_topnav(); ?>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Function:

```
function get_topnav(){
global $db;
$sql="SELECT i.name,i.href from index_pages i join top_menu t on t.index_page=i.id ";
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) {
echo  "<li><a href='".get_domain().$row['href']."'>".$row['name']."</a>";
//dropdownmenu
echo "</li>";
}
}
```

Now I have topmenu names and its all working fine, but I want to display my second pages in dropmenu view.

**Like:**

```
<header>
    <h1 class="header">Godhaze</h1>
    <nav id="nav-vasak">
    <ul>
    <li><a>Login</a> //mainpage
    <li><a>Action_log</a></li> //secondpage
   </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

**TABLE SECOND_PAGES**

```
id,    name,     index_page_id,                href
------------------------------------------------------------------
1     error_log       2           ?page=admin&secondpage=error_log    
2     user_log        2           ?page=admin&secondpage=user_log
3     action_log      1          ?page=login&secondpage=action_log
4     test_log        3           ?page=projects&secondpage=test_log
```

The table to know what secondpages can be displayed in the  dropdown top menu, index_page is the foreign key to index_pages and second_page is foreign key to second_pages

**TABLE TOP_MENU_PAGES**

```
id,    index_page, second_page
-------------------------------
1          1           3   
2          2           1
```

So now to my question is.. how can I make this function so I can display the second pages at dropdown menu?

Comment: You want a function which retrieve second pages data with respect to `index_page_id` key ?

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo Yes

Comment: then you can do that as you done for main page ,what was the issue ?

Comment: I meant something else,

Comment: Are you try with the modified function ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified function

```
function get_second_pages(){
 global $db;
 $sql="SELECT i.name,i.href,s.name as name2,s.href as href2,
       from index_pages i 
       join top_menu t on t.index_page=i.id 
       join SECOND_PAGES s on t.second_page=s.id ";
 foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo  "<li><a href='".get_domain().$row['href']."'>".$row['name']."</a>";
  echo  "<li><a href='".get_domain().$row['href2']."'>".$row['name2']."</a>";
  echo "</li>";
 }
}
```

I thing it will help you.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my explaining wasn't good enough,  but I want the second table items rows(items) to appear on dropmenu like <li><a>FIRST MENU ITEM</a><li><a>SECOND MENU ITEM</a></li></li>

Comment: Now use this modified function

Comment: Apparently this dosent work, because It needs to show the second pages what are children submenu of mainpages, but thanks for help, I guess this is harder than i thought..